# React array map error in production build

Tags: reactjs

I'm loading json data from an api and then map the data in a table. This is working fine in development but when I build my project I'm getting the error below. This error only occurs in the build version of my project. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Error in Chrome console:

```
TypeError: t.map is not a function
    at ce (InfopageTable.js:105)
    at oi (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Bi (react-dom.production.min.js:180)
    at Vc (react-dom.production.min.js:269)
    at Cl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at kl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at Sl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at hl (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
```

Load data from api:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    let cancel
    axios.get('info', {
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(c => cancel = c)
    }).then(res => {
        if(res.data.length > 0) {
            setData(res.data)
        }
        else {
            setData([])
        }
    }).catch(res => {
        setData([])
    }).then(() => {
        setLoading(false)
    })

    return () => cancel()
}, [])
```

Map the data:

```
{data.length > 0 && data.map(row => (
    <TableRow
        key={row.name}
        sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
        
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {row.name}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{row.value}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
            <CopyToClipboard text={row.value} onCopy={() => handleCopy()}>
                <IconButton>
                    <ContentCopyIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </CopyToClipboard>
            
            <IconButton aria-label="more" onClick={(e) => {
                handleClick(e)
                setItemId(row._id)
            }}>
                <MoreVertIcon />
            </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
))}
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why it would be happening in production only and not development, however when you are doing:

```
if(res.data.length > 0) {
  setData(res.data)
}
```

If res.data is a string, this will go through fine, and then later on you'll try calling map on a string which is an issue. Maybe you can be a bit safer and make sure that the data coming back isnt just a string but actually an array?

Comment: (e.g. `Array.isArray(res.data)`)

Comment: Tanks Abdullah! Your hint with the string solved my problem. In production my app connected to the wrong port of my api because an environment variable in Docker wasn't set correctly. I'll definetly implement you suggestion of handling a string if the api returns a string :)